# Subscribe to service making multiple parallel requests for each item in a list

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a component in Angular 5 that displays a list of items.
The items are populated by calling a service and subscribing to it.
The service needs to first make a request to get the list of items, which returns a list of 'events'. A new list myItems is built from this response.
Then, for each item, a new request is made to get the item's description and the item is updated with the result.
The data seems to be built correctly and the subscribe callback seems to be called, but my component template is displaying nothing.
I believe I am doing something wrong within the service (maybe with flatMap).

Component:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.itemsService.getItems()
        .subscribe((items: Item[]) => {
            // console.log(items) here seems fine, but the template does not display anything
            this.items = items;
        });
}
```

Component template:

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of items">
    <li>{{item.description}}</li>
 </ul>
```

Service:

```js
public getItems(): Observable<Item[]> {
    let myItems = [];

    return this.httpService.get('items')
        .map((response: any) => {
            if (response.events) {
                let eventObj: Item;
                for (let i = 0; i < response.events.length; i++) {
                    if (response.events[i]) {
                        eventObj = new Item(response.events[i]);
                        myItems.push(eventObj);
                    }
                }
            }
            return myItems;
        })
        .flatMap((items: Item[]) => {
            const itemsObservables = items
                .map((item: Item) => {
                    return this.itemService.getDescription(item.id)
                        .map((response) => {
                            item.description = response;
                            return item;
                        });
                });
            return Observable.forkJoin(itemsObservables)
                .map(data => {
                    return myItems;
                });
        });
}
```

Comment: you should avoid populating observable state and tracking it outside of the observable. That is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Thanks @pixelbits, could you clarify what should I change to avoid the anti-pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Avoid tracking observable state if it is not necessary. Assuming you have legitimate reasons for doing so, I believe you can fix your immediate issue by altering your last statement to use the spread operator:

```
return Observable.forkJoin(...itemsObservables);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your template is likely crashing due to latency which is to be expected in these types of asynchronous operation. Please change the syntax in your template for ALL nodes which access/display this data to something like this:

```
<li>{{item?.description}}</li>
```

In fact until you get it working, add the question mark to all the accessors in your template. Once you get something working you can pull them back as needed.

i.e. `<li>{{item?.entity?.name?.firstname}}</li>`

Hope this helps